# Does the retrieved OAuth2.0 authorization code for Azure AD web applications expire?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

In order to access resources in Azure AD web applications we retrieve an authorization code using the following workflow:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

Now my questions is, does this retrieved code also have a specific lifetime (like tokens have) or will it never expire? I guess it won't expire but I need to be sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the authorization code has a lifetime of 10 minutes I think.
You use it to get the tokens you need and then throw it away.
You'll get refresh tokens so you can use them to get more tokens later.
ADAL.NET for example handles the token refresh for you, assuming you properly implement a token cache.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-id-and-access-tokens (scroll all the way down) (it's for the v2.0 endpoint, but codes are similarly short-lived in v1)

> Authorization codes (work or school accounts)
>
> 10 minutes
>
> Authorization codes are purposely short-lived, and should be immediately redeemed for access tokens and refresh tokens when the tokens are received.

Comment: I did some manual testing, and could still exchange a code after waiting ~5-15 minutes. Waiting ~20 min consistently caused the code to expire. The [current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) is a bit inexact and says _"Typically, they expire after about 10 minutes."_, so maybe there is a bit of variation or headroom.

Comment: Just guessing but there could be multiple caching layers with different expiry times and then it's a bit random how those expiries combine.